# Accuracy and Statistical Significance

Tags: statistical-significance, classification

According to experimental result, one approach (Semantic Similarity based custom classifier) has 10% better accuracy over the other (Naive Bayes classifier) in a single domain. I would like to couple this accuracy result with the statistical significance (p-value).

The purpose of this statistical significance testing is to assess the performance of the classification between two appraoches. Such a test would validate the observed increase in accuracy of 10% and would show that it has not been obtained by chance.

Any idea how to calculate statistical significance in this context?

Since the comparison is between two different approaches on a single domain, I am considering the McNemar’s Chi-squared test with continuity correction.

Another note is the dataset has around 1300 records and I have used 5 fold cross validation.

**Updated the question as the question did not have much details. I am after any other approach I can use. Also it would be useful if any one explains why we need statistical significance besides cross validation (5 folds or 10 folds). Thanks...**

Comment: only if you described the context~ As it is the question is unanswerable.

Comment: Hi RCP. As it stands your question could really only be answered with 'it depends'. More context/detail is needed if this question is to stay open.

Comment: Seriously, is this a Stack Overflow Sokal Affair?

Answer (score 1):

As @user603 and @Glen_b said, you need to provide more information for this answer. Anyway, I am trying to give you my opinion.

Given the fact that you have posted this in classification, I guess that is the task, and without any other context, I would recommend the article by Yang et al on [A re-examination of text categorization methods](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~chin/702/sigir99.pdf) where the authors explain how to analyse the differences between classifiers.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

With the minimal info that you provided, there is one solution that requires a big leap of faith. Assuming that there is a binary gold standard and you have two sets of binary outputs (a la contingency tables), one per model, then, you simply have {$p_1$, $q_1$} and {$p_2$, $q_2$} for method 1 and 2 (chances for correct and incorrect answers). Now, assuming that the performance is normal, you can compare the two models by comparing the means of the two normals of the form $N(pq, npq)$. This will give you a P-value for the significance of the performance-difference.
Is this sth you want?